# Issue Starting Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to get the schema registry running and I am seeing the below exception.

```
ERROR Server died unexpectedly: 
    (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain:51)
    org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Only plaintext and SSL Kafka endpoints are supported and none are configured.
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.filterBrokerEndpoints(KafkaStore.java:271)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.<init>(KafkaStore.java:122)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.<init>(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:141)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:37)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:118)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
```

I am using Confluent 3.0.1 version and my kafka version is 0.10.0-2.11
Below are my properties.

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081  
kafkastore.connection.url=sl73caehdp0131.visa.com:2181,sl73caehdp0125.visa.com:2181
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=true
avro.compatibility.level=full
kafkastore.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

To Resolve the above issue, i added the below property to the properties file.

```
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://sl73caehdp0135.visa.com:9092
```

After adding this property, I get the exception

```
ERROR Error starting the schema registry 

  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:57) 

  io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:189)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:55)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:37)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:118)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
    Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: No live Kafka brokers
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createSchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:225)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:136)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:187)
    ... 4 more
```

What could be the mistake i am making, can any one please help.

Comment: At first glance, looks like SASL may not be supported. Can you try having only plaintext in the `security.protocol` settings?

Comment: Schema Registry does not support using Kafka brokers for the store address until a 4.x release. It needs to be Zookeeper for your version

Comment: I tried giving plaintext but it says that i couldnt find any brokers matching the security protocol as all our kafka brokers are configured to use SASL_PLAINTEXT security protocol.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I am aware of that but i just tried to add it and see if it gives me more information about the issue

Comment: Can you try grabbing a newer verison of Confluent and just configuring/running the Registry from it?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [3.0.1 Configuration Options](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/schema-registry/docs/config.html)

> `kafkastore.security.protocol`
>
> The security protocol to use when connecting with Kafka, the underlying persistent storage. Values can be PLAINTEXT or SSL.

Plus, as per [the Security Overview page](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/schema-registry/docs/security.html#kafka-store)

> At this time, ZooKeeper security and Kafka SASL authentication are not yet supported.

Until you upgrade to a version of at least `0.10.2` Kafka, you won't be able to use a newer version of the other components.

Ideally, they should all match, but the Schema Registry really just uses a regular consumer process, so having a newer client shouldn't be a problem for those newer versions, [assuming that the server will support it](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#id5)

> Schema Registry that is included in Confluent Platform 3.2 and later is compatible with any Apache Kafka broker that is included in Confluent Platform 3.0 and later

Comment: I tried using schema registry from the confluent version 3.3.2 and I was getting a message that it couldn't find any brokers matching the security protocol, all my brokers are configured to SASL_PLAINTEXT, what else could be the config i might be missing?

Comment: Can you try 4.1, or even 5.0? I don't know if/when SASL_PLAINTEXT support is ever added. Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself, but it's not clear how you are setting the JAAS file for the registry as it being a consumer.

Comment: I exported the jaas file path as an environment variable(java.security.auth.login.config) as I did for versions 5.0, it worked there

Comment: @sherenator Schema Registry isn't monetized. Not sure what you're problem is